# Producer-Consumer with semaphores gets deadlocked

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer

I'm trying to create Producer-Consumer with semaphores only. With following code

```
public class Application {

    public static int id = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Semaphore producerSem = new Semaphore(1);
        Semaphore consumerSem = new Semaphore(1);
        Queue<Integer> line = new LinkedList<>();

        Runnable produce = () -> {
            try {
                producerSem.acquire();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " producing");
                while (line.size() > 10) continue;
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                line.offer(id);
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " produced thing with id: " + id);
                id++;
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " finished producing");
                producerSem.release();

            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };

        Runnable consume = () -> {
            try {
                consumerSem.acquire();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " consuming");
                while (line.size() < 1) continue;
                int product = line.remove();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " consumed thing with id: " + product);
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " finished consuming");
                consumerSem.release();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            new Thread(consume, "Consumer - " + i).start();
            new Thread(produce, "Producer - " + i).start();
        }
    }
}
```

it gets deadlocked which I can't debug as it goes to id 10 and stops, so it looks like one element is removed but it won't manage to move forward. With breakpoint anywhere it works fine, even at the end of any task

Comment: I expected `Semaphore consumerSem = new Semaphore(0);` and `produce` to increase the `consumerSem`. And then a guarded change of the LinkedList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think is a nice exercice use only semaphores to write thread safe code.

You should protect three aspects:

- the `id` is a simple global integer and only one process should **write** at once.
- add or remove jobs to the queue should be protected also.
- although we can use the queue protection to check availability, an elegant way to wait for new jobs is use a synchronized counter (a semaphore). In this way, we do not adquire the queue only for check.

The modified code could be:

```
// our `id` counter...
private static int id = 0;
// ...and their semaphore for thread safety
private static Semaphore idSemaphore = new Semaphore(1);

// jobs queue...
private static Queue<Integer> lineJobs = new LinkedList<>();
// ...and their semaphore for thread safety
private static Semaphore lineSemaphore = new Semaphore(1);

// thread safe counter for (thread safety) jobs availability check
private static Semaphore lineSemaphoreAvailable = new Semaphore(0);

public static void main(String[] args) {


    Runnable produce = () -> {

        // we will set `myId` only once
        final int myId;

        // create a new id
        try {
            // wait to be granted to touch the global (unsafe integer) `id`
            idSemaphore.acquire();
            myId = id++;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.printf("%s: INTERRUPTED!%n", Thread.currentThread().getName());
            return;
        } finally {
            // with exception or not release the semaphore
            idSemaphore.release();
        }

        System.out.printf("%s: producing job #%d...%n", Thread.currentThread().getName(), myId);

        // producing job...
        try {
            Thread.sleep(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1000));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.printf("%s: INTERRUPTED!%n", Thread.currentThread().getName());
            return;
        }

        // store the job
        try {
            // wait to be granted to touch the global (unsafe queue) `lineJobs`
            lineSemaphore.acquire();
            lineJobs.add(myId);

            // notify to consumers a new one job is available to peek
            lineSemaphoreAvailable.release();

            System.out.printf("%s: job #%d ready to do!%n", Thread.currentThread().getName(), myId);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.printf("%s: INTERRUPTED!%n", Thread.currentThread().getName());
            return;
        } finally {
            lineSemaphore.release();
        }
    };

    Runnable consume = () -> {

        final int myId;

        // get a job
        try {
            // wait for a new job to become available
            lineSemaphoreAvailable.acquire();
            
            // wait to be granted to touch the global (unsafe queue) `lineJobs`
            lineSemaphore.acquire();
            myId = lineJobs.remove();
            System.out.printf("%s: job #%d adquired%n", Thread.currentThread().getName(), myId);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.printf("%s: INTERRUPTED!%n", Thread.currentThread().getName());
            return;
        } finally {
            lineSemaphore.release();
        }

        System.out.printf("%s: job #%d finished!%n", Thread.currentThread().getName(), myId);
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        new Thread(consume, "Consumer - " + i).start();
        new Thread(produce, "Producer - " + i).start();
    }
}
```

with output

```
Producer - 0: producing job #0...
Producer - 1: producing job #1...
...
Producer - 46: producing job #45...
Producer - 45: producing job #44...
Producer - 9: job #9 ready to do!
Producer - 44: producing job #46...
Producer - 47: producing job #47...
Producer - 48: producing job #48...
Producer - 49: producing job #49...
Consumer - 0: job #9 adquired
Consumer - 0: job #9 finished!
Producer - 14: job #14 ready to do!
Consumer - 1: job #14 adquired
Consumer - 1: job #14 finished!
Producer - 50: producing job #50...
Producer - 51: producing job #51...
...
Producer - 72: producing job #72...
Producer - 39: job #39 ready to do!
Consumer - 2: job #39 adquired
Consumer - 2: job #39 finished!
Producer - 73: producing job #73...
Producer - 74: producing job #74...
Producer - 75: producing job #75...
Producer - 10: job #10 ready to do!
Producer - 40: job #40 ready to do!
Consumer - 3: job #10 adquired
Consumer - 3: job #10 finished!
Producer - 76: producing job #76...
Producer - 77: producing job #77...
...
Producer - 82: producing job #82...
Producer - 83: producing job #83...
Producer - 84: producing job #84...
Consumer - 4: job #40 adquired
Consumer - 4: job #40 finished!
Producer - 85: producing job #85...
Producer - 86: producing job #86...
Producer - 71: job #71 ready to do!
Producer - 87: producing job #87...
Consumer - 5: job #71 adquired
Consumer - 5: job #71 finished!
Producer - 88: producing job #88...
Producer - 92: producing job #92...
Producer - 91: producing job #91...
...
Producer - 96: producing job #95...
Producer - 98: producing job #98...
Producer - 99: producing job #99...
Producer - 84: job #84 ready to do!
Consumer - 6: job #84 adquired
Consumer - 6: job #84 finished!
...
Consumer - 97: job #63 adquired
Consumer - 97: job #63 finished!
Producer - 90: job #90 ready to do!
Consumer - 98: job #90 adquired
Consumer - 98: job #90 finished!
Producer - 87: job #87 ready to do!
Consumer - 99: job #87 adquired
Consumer - 99: job #87 finished!

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: So now, both Consumers and Producers are guarded with one semaphore. Is it impossible for them to access non thread safe collection at the same time?

Comment: Yes, is impossible, in the example, exactly each producer produce one and only one job and each consumer consume one and only one job and the program ends fine.